# helm secrets that replace variables inside configurations files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy a rest api application in kubernetes with helm. Some of the configuration files have credentials in them and I would like to replace the variables inside the helm templates during the deployment with Kubernetes secrets.

Does anyone have a pointer to a documentation where I can explore this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Secret template in your templates folder. Then, you can pass the values through helm cli.

For example, here is my `secret.yaml` file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: {{ .Values.password | b64enc }}
```

Now, I can set the value for `password` as bellow:

```
helm install  my-chart-instance my-chart -n my-namespace --set password=my-secret-value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I was wondering how I can insert one of the secrets in a configuration file and helm will replace it while deploying the statefulset. Basically a template that will contain a variable from the kubernetes secrets

Comment: I have some rest api configuration that contains a secret. Instead of the real exposed credential I will use helm variable that will be replaced with the read secret once helm will deploy the statefulset ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking forward to directly deploy the `ENV` to the deployment file you can also do it if you can few environment variables however best practices to create the **secret** and inject them all into the **deployment**.

here sharing the direct example to inject the secret into the deployment

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{  .Chart.Name }}-deployment"
  labels:
    chart: '{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}'
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "{{  .Chart.Name }}-selector"
      version: "current"
  revisionHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.revisionHistoryLimit }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "{{  .Chart.Name }}-selector"
        version: "current"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "{{  .Chart.Name  }}"
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.servicePort}}
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "{{ .Values.image.resources.requests.cpu }}"
            memory: "{{ .Values.image.resources.requests.memory }}"
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value : "{{ .Values.service.servicePort }}"
        {{- if .Values.image.livenessProbe }}
        livenessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.image.livenessProbe | indent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.image.readinessProbe }}
        readinessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.image.readinessProbe | indent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
image:
  repository: nodeserver
  tag: 1.0.0
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 300Mi
  readinessProbe: {}
  # Example (replace readinessProbe: {} with the following):
  # readinessProbe:
  #   httpGet:
  #     path: /ready
  #     port: 3000
  #   initialDelaySeconds: 3
  #   periodSeconds: 5
  livenessProbe: {}
  # Example (replace livenessProbe: {} with the following)::
  # livenessProbe:
  #   httpGet:
  #     path: /live
  #     port: 3000
  #   initialDelaySeconds: 40
  #   periodSeconds: 10  
service:
  name: Node
  type: NodePort
  servicePort: 3000
```

you can see inside the deployment.yaml code block

```
env:
          - name: PORT
            value : "{{ .Values.service.servicePort }}"
```

it's fetching the values from `values.yaml` file

```
service:
  name: Node
  type: NodePort
  servicePort: 3000
```

if you don't want to update the `values.yaml` file you can rewrite the value using the command also

```
helm install chart my-chart -n namespace-name --set service.servicePort=5000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this !! Can the same be applied for a template yaml block?
If I have the configuration of my rest api in a configmap, is it possible to already sue the secret as variable inside the values yaml block?
Thanks a lot again

Comment: Sorry not getting your issue can you please explain more about api. Yes same can be applied to template part also Helm is configurable so you can create any type of chart based on requirement. Sorry but not getting api part.

Comment: If you already configmap better inject or map the configmap in deployment.